# function producing space charcters for the generated password

Tags: php

I am not understanding why below function producing space characters for generated password.

```
function generateRandomPassword($length) {
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $password = "";
    $vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
    $cons = array(
         "b", "c", "d", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r",
         "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "tr", "cr", "br", "fr", "th", "dr",
         "ch",  "ph", "wr", "st", "sp", "sw", "pr", "sl", "cl"
    );
    $num_vowels = count($vowels);
    $num_cons = count($cons);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $c = $cons[rand(0, $num_cons - 1)];
         if (rand(0,1)) {
             $c = strtoupper($c);
         }
         $v = $vowels[rand(0, $num_vowels - 1)];
         if (rand(0,1)) {
             $v = strtoupper($v);
         }
         $password .= $c . $v;
         if (rand(0,4) == 0) {
            $password .= rand(0,9);
         }
      }

      return trim(substr($password, 0, $length));
   }
```

Comment: I ran this on my machine, and I don't have any space character in generated password string

Comment: Tested your function, it doesn't seem to be producing any spaces. Why don't you simplify your function like this: `function generateRandomPassword($length = 8) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $password = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, $length);
    return $password;
}`

Comment: I wasn't getting any spaces either

Comment: Space character not getting alwayz. space character showing intermittently. if u run above fucntion like 20 times, you will see a space character at one time.

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't able to get any spaces in your given code but I would recommend highly simplifying this

```
function generateRandomPassword($length) {
    $rand = substr(hash('sha512', microtime()),rand(0,26),$length);
    echo $rand;
}
```